# How set checkbox in Acrobat javascript?

Tags: javascript, checkbox, adobe, acrobat

how can i set value for checkbox in pdf form in Adobe Acrobat?

I have russian localization of Acrobat XI, and i figured out that this works:

this.getField("checkboxID").value = "Да".

(Word in quotation marks is Yes in russian language).

As i have googled people say i must put value "On".

but in russian locale it doen't accept On. If i try place anything except russian word yes ("Да") it clears checkbox.

My customers can have russian and english localiztion of acrobat.
So if i use russian word yes, it will work in russian version of adobe, but i suppose it will not work in english version.
How can i set checkbot in any language?

Answer (score 0):

I found this solution:

```
var checked = "On";
if(app.language == 'RUS')
{
   checked = "Да";
}

this.getField("checkboxID").value = checked.
```

but it seems a bit ugly solution.

Comment: ugly solution, and it won't work, unless you did set the return value of the field to "On".

Comment: It works in russian version. In English version i must set to "On".

Answer (score 0):

You actually have several possibilities:

a) You check that field, then open the Console and let you display the value of the field with this line of code:

```
this.getField("myCheckBox").value ;
```

To check this particular box, you would then use that return value (to uncheck, you would set its value to `"Off"`). (note: "unchecked" is always the value `"Off"`, and can be used generally; this opposed to no generally used value for "checked").

b) you have a look at the `checkThisBox()` method in the Acrobat Javascript documentation. This method counts the widgets of the field (the individual boxes) in their order of creation, and allows you to check and uncheck a particular widget. It is not dependent on the value of the box, and therefore also not dependent on any localization issues.